# How do I kill a php script from another php script?

Tags: php, linux

I would like to kill a php script, say script `A.php`, (while it is running) from inside another php script say script `B.php`. When script `A.php` starts I would like to save some kind of `ID` into the database. When script `B.php` starts running I want to get that `ID` from the database and use that to `exit` or `kill` script `A.php` inmediately.

Is this possible, and how can I do that?

UPDATE 1

There can be multiple instances of A.php in which case I only want to kill a single instance of A.php. I can get the Process ID at the beginning of each script and save it either in a database or SESSION variable B.php knows which A.php script to kill.

This application is used within the backend program of a website. The reason for killing the scripts A.php is because some users click on many buttons which trigger A.php to run. As A.php takes around 5 seconds to run and only the latest version of A.php is required I would like to kill other A.php scripts that are still running to save server resources as I am not interesting in the outcome anymore.

Comment: This sounds like a somewhat odd approach. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you have any code that you would like to share?

Comment: It looks like either you picked the wrong language for your task, or your project design is bad. In ideal world PHP scripts run once and terminate.

Comment: Perhaps what you mean is that you would like to control whether a user can use script A using a flag set by script B?  Is that it?  Because killing the script means stopping one use, causes a server error, and can be messy visually. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: @Paul: not only visually....

Comment: @BartFriederichs Correct. By killing the script, you could leave your database in an unexpected state or cause other problems.

Comment: @Paul but would it be safe to do kill command on scripts that do not interact with the database? e.g. Just copying images from another server?

Comment: @JomarSevillejo Terminating a remote copy is more complicated than simply calling kill on a php script. Of course, you can do that, but there are unforeseen complexities. Generally, a script often will spawn shell commands to do the file copying, which have their own PID numbers to kill and if you don't kill those too, they may keep running.  Also, if you manage to kill any script children, you still need to clean up by deleting any partial file copies.  If partial copies  are not detectable, it is safest to delete everything copied from the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To kill scriptA.php from scriptB.php you must be able to execude system commands, and you should not running this within a webserver.

You could store the `pid` of `scriptA.php` within the database. To get it use [getmypid()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.getmypid.php).
In `scriptB.php` you could use the `system()` function to kill the other process:

```
system("kill $pidOfScriptA");
```

Comment: What if you are running PHP on windows?